# Perl regex search and replace with $variable->function("args")

Tags: regex, string, perl

Basically I'm trying to replace with whatever is returned from a function call from an object. But I need a return value from the regex search as the argument. It's a little tricky but the code should speak for itself:

```
while ( $token =~ s/\$P\(([a-z0-9A-Z_]+)\)/$db->getValue("params", qw($1))/e ) { }
```

The error I'm getting is that $1 is not getting evaluated to anything (the argument literally becomes "$1") so it screws up my getValue() method.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `qw()` functions quotes "words". I.e. it splits a string at all whitespace characters and returns that list. It *does not* interpolate.

You can just use the variable "as is":

```
s/\$P\(([a-z0-9A-Z_]+)\)/$db->getValue("params", $1)/e
```

The `qw()` function is very different from

- `q(abc)`  (<=> `'abc'`),
- `qq(abc)` (<=> `"abc"`),    and
- `qx(abc)` (<=> `` `abc` ``) or
- `qr(abc)` (<=> `m/abc/`):

`qw(a b c)` <=> `('a', 'b', 'c')`

Comment: You're right, I was using the qw() function incorrectly. Turns out I don't need it. Thanks bro.